# Importing Music Player into another project, no errors found but playback doesn't work?

Tags: android, eclipse

I had two projects, one called myLauncher and another called the RandomMusicPlayer sample from the Android SDK. The music player worked fine alone but when I imported it into my project it stopped working, the strange thing is that it doesn't give any errors nor no errors are found in eclipse, it just doesn't play music. (I had merged projects before and did everything like changing R import, imporing the layout, image files and correcting the manifest)

These are the current contents of /src:

```
> src > com.mylauncher.launcher
      > com.mylauncher.easyplayer > MainActivity.java
                                  > MusicService.java
```

When I click on Play on the player an alert is fired, which I added for debugging, so the button is working ok. Just after the alert there is the line that starts playback:

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Argh").setMessage("Watch out!").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
    startService(new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PLAY));
```

While I can trace the code to the alert it seems the following intent never starts. (I added an alert inside MusicService and it doesn't run.)

Eclipse doens't show any errors and I can run the APP just fine (just no music is played) morover the app works ok alone. Any idea what can be the problem? Do I have to do something extra after importing the package to ensure it works properly?

Comment: Can you provide some detail what you mean by this? "(apart from correcting the manifest, R import and importing layouts and images)"

Comment: yes, after importing any package files there are a number of couple of things that have to be done, like in my case changing import com.randommusicplayer.R; to import com.mylauncher.R; and adding appending the contents of <application> from the old manifest to the project is being imported too. After doing both these things Eclipse stop showing errors. Then I runned the app normally, but playback simply didn't work.

Comment: Delete your project.  Try importing it without changing the name.  In eclipse, go to import.  Use "import Existing Projects into Workspace" instead of "Existing Android code...".  Accept all of the defaults and don't change things like the name.  Once imported, you might have to build the project if you don't have that set automatically.  Then report back.